# Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379] Laravel Predis

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I'm trying to setup Redis client to connect to the Redis server in Laravel 6.0 version, but when I try to change the REDIS_HOST  in database.php file in config it gives me an error:

> Connection refused 127.0.0.1:6379

This is how my code looks like in routes `api.php` file

```php
Route::get('test',function(Request $request){

  $redis=Redis::connection();
  $redis->set("key1","keyValue");
  $a=$redis->get("key1");
  return response()->json( ['test'=>$a,]);
});
```

and this is how my `database.php` file looks like

```php
      'redis' => [

            'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
                'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
            ],

            'default' => [
                'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
                'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
                'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
            ],

            'cache' => [
                'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
                'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
                'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
            ],
        ],
```

So when i change the REDIS_HOST its gives me error,any idea  is my code problem the configurations?

Thanks !

Comment: I mostly get `Connection refused 127.0.0.1:6379` error when I forgot to turn on the redis server itself. Are you sure your redis server is running?

Comment: Yes, its running,but its not running on my local machine ,its running on my Linux ubuntu server.

Comment: Solved it : My code was the problem: missing part to it:
    $client=new Predis\Client('tcp://ipadress:6379?database=0');
    $a =$client->get('data');

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this on my MacBook and fixed it by installing Redis using homebrew as directed [here](https://gist.github.com/tomysmile/1b8a321e7c58499ef9f9441b2faa0aa8)

PS: I'm working with Laravel 8.40